# How to reverse time stamp using javascript/Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need one help.I need to display the existing time stamp in reverse format using Angular.js/Javascript. I am explaining my code below.

```
$scope.timestamp=2016-12-16 07:02:15 am
```

I have the time stamp like above.but i need to reverse the above value like below.

```
$scope.originalStamp=16/12/2016 07:02:15 am
```

So i need convert the format like above. Please help me.

Comment: You can use moment.js or a similar library - it makes it easier than manually doing it as JS doesn't have good support for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using angular. So please try with using `$filter`

```
   $scope.timestamp =  '2016-12-16 07:02:15 am'
   $scope.originalStamp = $filter('date')
                          (new Date($scope.timestamp.replace("-","/")),'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a');
```

### [Updated Demo](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FBFW1RJ3GX08)

here is the full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl">

<p> {{originalStamp}} </p>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope,$filter) {

   $scope.timestamp =  '2016-12-16 07:02:15 am'
  $scope.originalStamp = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.timestamp.replace("-","/")),'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a');

});
</script>

<p>The date filter formats a date object to a readable format.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Time is not coming only date coming.

Answer (score 0):

Why not format a date from the original timestamp. You can format it however you like.

```
var date= new Date(timestamp);

var formatDate = function(date){
    return date.getDate() + "/" + date.getMonth() + "/" +date.getYear() + " "+  date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getMintutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
}

$scope.myDate = formatDate(date);
```

Answer (score -1):

`ng-bind="usercart.date|date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'"` here you can define as you want date format....

add this code `ng-bind="usercart.date|date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'"`

output  :

`Last Updated Cart 05-01-2017 14:58:38`

Comment: what is `usercart.date` and here i have `$scope.timestamp=2016-12-16 07:02:15 am` and i have to make as per expected.

Comment: where you bind add this as angularjs filter date:'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a'

Comment: <p ng-bind="originalStamp  |  date:'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a'"></p>

Answer (score -2):

here you go

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.date='2016-12-16 07:02:15 am';
  $scope.req = function(date){
          var dateOut = new Date(date);
          return dateOut;
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p ng-bind="req(date) |  date:'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a'"></p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @RameshRajendran http://plnkr.co/edit/3CuzCLS8CByBUdMC1Toh?p=preview check this i didnt get any

Comment: `invalid date`.

Comment: Also if you run your snippet. it's also threw the same invalid date error

Comment: i am not getting anything like that in my machine i had tried in different browsers